# Windows 7 stuck at Welcome screen

Tags: windows-7, boot

I got into a problem where Windows 7 got stuck at the Welcome screen. I checked some online forums where it says can be easily rectified by getting into safe mode. 
But safe mode also got stuck at the Welcome screen.

Then I tried booting with Windows 7 DVD to repair my Windows. It's not working as it get restarted without entering into the setup. Is there any problem with my hardware?

How do I repair this?

Comment: Check SMART status of hard drive with GSmartControl, if it will show any light red or dark red rows in attributes, it is means HDD is failing. Check also RAM with Memtest86+. If its works, try to boot with Live linux CD such as SystemRescueCD, if it stuck too, then it is more serious damage. I stepped on that two days ago, a company we serving got stroked by lightning and one of their PC start doing exactly the same as you described. Checked RAM and HDD, both are Ok, but something happened on motherboard, so even Linux got stuck when switching to protected mode on start.

Comment: Thanks @Alex. I will try that. Hope these tool are available with Hiren boot Cd

Comment: [GSmartControl  is here](https://gsmartcontrol.sourceforge.io/home/index.php/Downloads) and MemTest86 is for sure on Hiren CD. You probably would need  another computer to test HDD, since yours won't boot. If you would use [SystemRescueCD](http://www.system-rescue-cd.org) you can check SMART attributes as `smartctl -a /dev/sda`

Comment: Try to run Repair when booting.